# Raspberry Pi ad-hoc: Awkward ping statistics

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, ad-hoc-network

I connected two Raspberry Pi 3 Model B via ad-hoc, using two **TP-LINK TL-WN722N** wireless adapters.

I used these commands to configure ad-hoc networking:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode ad-hoc essid PIWLAN channel 5
sudo ifconfig wlan1 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
```

The structure of icmp requests is always the same:

- 5 Packets with a ping of ~ 5 ms *(fine)*
- 2 Packets with a ping of ~ 1000 ms *(fatal for my project)*
- 5 Packets with a ping of ~ 5 ms
- 2 Packets with a ping of ~ 1000 ms

After some research, I figured out that my wireless adapter has ad-hoc problems. Therefore I configured the first Pi as an access point. The icmp requests were fine.

I bought two other wireless adapters (Edimax AC600, EW-7811USC) and replaced the old ones. Configured both for ad-hoc mode. But the icmp peaks stay the same.

*Additional information: Both Pis are placed side by side and there is a packet loss of 0%.*

Comment: how much distance or obstacles are in between?

Comment: no obstacles and no distance

Comment: Your project is using ICMP?

Comment: No, my project is using UDP. But the problems did not relate to the protocol. See my own answer below, I fixed the problem. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/AdHoc

It works now. The URL above shows two methods of configuring ad-hoc mode.

When I had the timing problems, the configuration was based on the **manual method**. Using the URLs **debian method** eliminates the problem.

Does anyone know why?